# ng-include not working IE8

Tags: angularjs

I have kept my code at this plunker:

- http://plnkr.co/edit/EvjX6O?p=preview

My problem is that while loading in IE8 tree is getting generated but data is not coming corresponding to nodes.

Also node clicking is not working.

Answer (score 0):

ng-include does not work in IE8, please see the IE compatibility doc for AngularJS.